# How To Match Several non-www Host Headers Using IIS7 Rewrite Module

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I need to redirect several host headers without www. to their www. counterpart. I can't seem to get it working quite right. This is what I've got so far:

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The domains are all totally different, so there is no common string to match except for .com.

My regex is probably not right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\..*" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

EDIT:  fixed regex, should work now.

Comment: Thanks Scott! That worked perfectly. It sure is a time saver when you need to redirect over a hundred host headers to the www version.